# What is the meaning of "at one end"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I read about negative inversion grammar and I am faced with this sentence below which I don't know the meaning of "at on end":

> No sooner had the paint dried ***at one end*** than it needed repainting.

Comment: You start painting at one end of the item (say the [Forth Bridge](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+painting+the+Forth+Bridge)) and you finish at the other end. By the time you have done that the paint has dried at the end where you started.

Comment: @WeatherVane - this is one of those 'cool facts' that go around. "Painting the Forth Bridge" is a colloquial expression for a never-ending task, coined on the erroneous belief that at one time in the history of the bridge repainting was required and commenced immediately upon completion of the previous repaint. Such a practice never existed, as weathered areas were given more attention, but there was a permanent maintenance crew. Anyway, in 2011, the bridge was coated in a modern three-pack paint system that should last 25 years, and there is no longer a permanently employed paint crew.

Answer (score 0):

If you picture that whatever it is the speaker is painting has two [ends](https://www.google.com/search?q=end%20meaning&biw=1372&bih=661&sxsrf=AOaemvLASnswSdqcylSnfWlWjTNP6o29LQ%3A1630740900641&ei=pCEzYYXUJvCBhbIP8Nqq4Ag&oq=end%20mea&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQgAQQRhD5ATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoFCC4QgAQ6BAgAEEM6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BQguEJECOggIABCxAxCRAjoECC4QQzoICC4QkQIQkwI6CgguELEDEIMBEENKBAhBGABQuJACWOWhAmCOrAJoAHACeACAAXiIAeEFkgEDMi41mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) (check meaning 2 of the link), then by the time you finish painting the object ***from one end to the other***, the paint dries ***at the first end*** and you need to start all over again to add another coat.